# Spring Boot RestTemplate ClientHttpRequestInterceptor log response body in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, interceptor

I'm using a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to report request-out and response-in of a RestTemplate. I need to log the response in case of exception, let's say if the template is trying to unmashall the response with the wrong class.

This is how the interceptor is enabled:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(ReportingConfiguration reportingConfiguration) {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .interceptors(new RestTemplateInterceptor())
            .build();
}
```

The only interface accepted here is ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
The interceptor looks like:

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest req, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

    ...

    ClientHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = execution.execute(request, body);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("I need to get the response here");
    }

    ...
```

I know with this class it's not possible to get the response, could you please give an alternative solution?

this is an example of the exception: (please don't explain how to get rid of this exception, I know why I get this, I just want to log the payload in case this is happening)

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "items" (class com.exapmle.group.web.beans.Response), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "text", "status", "set-cookies"])
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.exapmle.group.web.beans.Response["items"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)`

Comment: Can you give more code and the stacktrace?

Comment: See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor).

Answer (score 0):

This is old question Still I will answer incase anyone is looking. I am able to get the Response with below configuration in case of API errors with http codes such as 500.

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        factory.setReadTimeout(5000); 

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(factory));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new CustomLoggingRequestInterceptor()));

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Now for Logging Interceptor.

```
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        traceRequest(request, body);
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        traceResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        inputStringBuilder.append(new String(getResponseBody(response), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         log.error(inputStringBuilder.toString()); 
      }
   
    protected byte[] getResponseBody(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        try {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(response.getBody());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

Comment: execution.execute(request, body); throws an exception so traceResponse(response); is never executed.

Answer (score -2):

This should work :

```
ClientHttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = execution.execute(request, body);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("I need to get the response here", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This way I just see the exception but not the payload

Comment: What exactly is the exception you are getting. ? Can you please post it.

Comment: what do you mean?